# How to insert pytube extension on my project

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytube

my code start with:

```
"from pytube import YouTube"
an the error is:
unresolved import 'pytube
```

How can i inport pytube library?

Comment: Please read [ask] and edit your question with a [mre].

Comment: @Νικόλας -How are things going? Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

For the use of the module "pytube" in VS Code, you could refer to the following:

1. Please check whether the python used by the terminal is the same as the python currently selected (Shown in the lower left corner of VS Code.) by VS Code: (`pip --version` or `python --version`)

   [image]

   If they are not the same, please use the shortcut key Ctrl+Shift+` to open a new terminal, it will automatically enter the selected environment.
2. Install the module. (`pip install pytube`)
3. Check: (`pip show pytube`)

   [image]

run:

[image]